# Boost.Log Installation Error on Boost 1.52.0

Tags: logging, boost

I tried to compile Boost.Log into the boost_1_52_0.  Once I came to the point to execute the following commands:

C:\boost_1_52_0>bjam --with-log variant=debug define=BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR define=B
OOST_LOG_USE_WINNT6_API stage --build-type=complete --link=
Performing configuration checks

The compilation is not completed, and generated less lib files, once I wrote a hello world program to utilize boost.log, it complaint the error "Error 2 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib'.

The following is the output:

```
    - has_icu builds           : no

Component configuration:

    - chrono                   : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 9657 targets...
...updating 17 targets...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\text_file_ba
ckend.obj
text_file_backend.cpp
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(956) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conver
sion from 'unsigned short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C2039: 'get_generic_category' :
 is not a member of 'boost::system'
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1169) : while compiling class templat
e member function 'void boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>
::do_consume(const boost::log_mt_nt6::basic_record<CharT> &,const std::basic_str
ing<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
        with
        [
            CharT=char,
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
        ]
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1439) : see reference to class templa
te instantiation 'boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>' bein
g compiled
        with
        [
            CharT=char
        ]
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C3861: 'get_generic_category':
identifier not found

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\text_f
ile_backend.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\te
xt_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log-vc1
00-mt-gd-1_52.dll for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-
multi>text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log-vc1
00-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-
multi>text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log-vc1
00-mt-gd-1_52.pdb for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-
multi>text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.dll for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\
log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.dll...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\
log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log_set
up-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.dll for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\thre
ading-multi>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log_set
up-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\thre
ading-multi>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log_set
up-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.pdb for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\thre
ading-multi>boost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.dll for lack of <pbin.v2
\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_52
.dll...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2
\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi>boost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_52
.lib...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\
text_file_backend.obj
text_file_backend.cpp
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(956) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conver
sion from 'unsigned short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C2039: 'get_generic_category' :
 is not a member of 'boost::system'
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1169) : while compiling class templat
e member function 'void boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>
::do_consume(const boost::log_mt_nt6::basic_record<CharT> &,const std::basic_str
ing<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
        with
        [
            CharT=char,
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
        ]
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1439) : see reference to class templa
te instantiation 'boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>' bein
g compiled
        with
        [
            CharT=char
        ]
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C3861: 'get_generic_category':
identifier not found

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-
multi\text_file_backend.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\thread
ing-multi\text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi>l
ibboost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\d
ebug\link-static\threading-multi>text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_log-vc100-mt-gd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\li
bs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_log-vc100-mt-g
d-1_52.lib...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-sta
tic\threading-multi\text_file_backend.obj
text_file_backend.cpp
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(956) : warning C4244: 'initializing' : conver
sion from 'unsigned short' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C2039: 'get_generic_category' :
 is not a member of 'boost::system'
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1169) : while compiling class templat
e member function 'void boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>
::do_consume(const boost::log_mt_nt6::basic_record<CharT> &,const std::basic_str
ing<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
        with
        [
            CharT=char,
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
        ]
        libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1439) : see reference to class templa
te instantiation 'boost::log_mt_nt6::sinks::basic_text_file_backend<CharT>' bein
g compiled
        with
        [
            CharT=char
        ]
libs\log\src\text_file_backend.cpp(1197) : error C3861: 'get_generic_category':
identifier not found

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-li
nk-static\threading-multi\text_file_backend.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtim
e-link-static\threading-multi\text_file_backend.obj...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-stat
ic\threading-multi>libboost_log-vc100-mt-sgd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\
log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi>text_f
ile_backend.obj...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_log-vc100-mt-sgd-1_52.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\l
ibs\log\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-static\threading-multi>li
bboost_log-vc100-mt-sgd-1_52.lib...
...failed updating 3 targets...
...skipped 14 targets...
```

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trying, there is an issue on boost filesyetem V3 on Boost 1.52.0, which is not compatible with boost.log Version 1.1.  So, it need to use "svn" to download the Boost.Log v2 trunk.  The command is the following:

svn co https://boost-log.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/boost-log boost-log

Then, I perform the following steps:

1. Copy the "boost\log" folder form boost-log to the "\boost_1_52_0\boost" folder
2. Copy the "libs\log" folder from boost-log to the "\boost_1_52_0\libs" folder
3. In command prompt, go the "boost_1_52_0" folder, execute "bootstrap.bat --show-libraries"
4. In the "boost_1_52_0" folder, execute "b2.exe"

Finger cross, you may receive the following message at the end of the compilation.

```
...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\threading-mult
i\default_filter_factory.obj
default_filter_factory.cpp
msvc.archive bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\threading-multi
\libboost_log_setup-vc100-mt-1_52.lib
common.copy stage\lib\libboost_log_setup-vc100-mt-1_52.lib
bin.v2\libs\log\build\msvc-10.0\release\link-static\threading-multi\libboost_log
_setup-vc100-mt-1_52.lib
        1 file(s) copied.
...updated 87 targets...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    D:/boost_1_52_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    D:\boost_1_52_0\stage\lib
```

Comment: Good one. This is certainly relevant as of 2012-12-07

Answer (score 2):

This version of Boost.Log uses deprecated 'get_generic_category()' function, which is now removed from Boost.System. So, you can either downgrade Boost, or patch manually Boost.Log changing `get_generic_category()` to `generic_category()` (and also `get_system_category()` to `system_category()` etc).

**UPDATE** it seems that I'm mistaken: according to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html), the above functions are still present, unless BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED is defined. So check if Boost.Log defines it.